# DIV Box Will Not Align

Tags: css, html, css-float

I've been going through documentation, tutorials and examples. But I can't seem to get these 4 boxes to align properly no matter what I do.

```
div#frontpage{width:100%; }
div#1{width:25%; float:left; position:relative;}
div#2{width:25%; float:left; position:relative;}
div#3{width:25%; float:right; position:relative;}
div#4{width:25%; float:right; position:relative;}
.clear{clear:both;}

<div id="frontpage">
<div id="1">
</div>
<div id"2">
</div>
<div id="3">
</div>
<div id="4">
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
</div>
```

This is what I came up so far and the closest result I want to achieve. Get them to all align horizontal straight across one row. The reason why I use % instead of px is because my wordpress theme is responsive.

Comment: Element IDs must begin with a letter, and please define "align properly", how improper is it right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tweaked it a bit and it works fine.
CSS

```
div#frontpage{width:100%; }
div.box{width:25%; float:left; position:relative;}
.clear{clear:both;}​
```

HTML

```
<div id="frontpage">
<div class="box">
    a
</div>
<div class="box">
    s
</div>
<div class="box">
    d
</div>
<div class="box">
    f
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

As mentioned by Phil, Ids should not be numbers. Also, your `<div id"2">` should have been `<div id="2">` (missing '=' sign)

Comment: Thanks I'll take note not to use numbers as IDs.

Answer (score 0):

see this working example http://jsfiddle.net/QFMXx/
change Id's in your code. Id's shouldn't start with digits

```
<div id="frontpage">
   <div id="d1">sfdfs
   </div>
   <div id="d2">dfsdf
   </div>
   <div id="d3">dsfsdf
   </div>
   <div id="d4">dfsfsd
   </div>
   <div class="clear">sdfsd
   </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
div#frontpage{width:100%; }
div#d1{width:25%; float:left; position:relative;}
div#d2{width:25%; float:left; position:relative;}
div#d3{width:25%; float:right; position:relative;}
div#d4{width:25%; float:right; position:relative;}
.clear{clear:both;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code little bit and got the result. Could you please try this?

```
<style>div#frontpage{width:100%; height:50%;border:1px solid red }
div.s1{width:25%; height:50%;float:left; position:relative;border:1px solid blue;clear:both}
.clear{clear:both;}
</style>
<div id="frontpage">
<div class="s1">
</div>
<div class="s1">
</div>
<div class="s1">
</div>
<div class="s1">
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
</div>  
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

--Felix

Answer (score 0):

Id must not start with a number. and maybe you can use the following style

```
    <style>
div#frontpage{width:100%;background-color:#ccc; }
div#a1{width:25%; float:left; position:relative;background-color:red;margin-right:75%;}
div#a2{width:25%; float:left; position:relative;background-color:#ffccea;margin:0 50% 0 -75%}
div#a3{width:25%; float:right; position:relative;background-color:blue;margin:0 25% 0 -50%}
div#a4{width:25%; float:right; position:relative;background-color:yellow;margin:0 0 0 -25%}
.clear{clear:both;}
</style>
```

I used a margin to the right to push away all the elements and a negetive margin to the left to pull up my desired elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
div#frontpage{width:100%;  position:relative;}
div#a{width:25%; float:left; }
div#b{width:25%; float:left; }
div#c{width:25%; float:right;}
div#d{width:25%; float:right;}
.clear{clear:both;}

<div id="frontpage">
<div id="a"></div>
<div id"b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I am not sure,